Remove www. from sitemap links generated by OSMap
Is there any way to do so? I can't find any option, neither any documentation for this, so I assume some code will have to be modified.

This worked:

I changed empty live_site in configuration.php to one without www
this broke the OSMap plugin, which returned 404s for the sitemaps, so I reverted to empty one
somehow, after going back, URLs were without www... Including new ones, freshly added to the menu. But it later went back, I assume after some cache refresh.

Then I verified why it breaks - CORS issue due to www which was added in admin panel randomly. So forcing redirection in .htaccess:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

fixed it fully.
I switched to JLSitemap that supports Phoca for free anyways, but hopefully it'll help someone.
